# Binance API and angular 4 httpClient

Tags: javascript, angular, http, typescript, cors

I have a question about cryptomarket Binance.
They have public api which I though I could use in angular to create trading app.

But I have some troubles.
Using that link in chrome I get json result.
https://api.binance.com/api/v1/exchangeInfo

But using with angular 4 httpClient:

```
this.http.get('https://api.binance.com/api/v1/exchangeInfo').subscribe(res => console.log(res));
```

I have error: Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at api.binance.com/api/v1/exchangeInfo. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing)

It doesn't work. I don't get it, why I can't use that API in angular app?https://github.com/binance-exchange/binance-official-api-docs/blob/master/rest-api.md

What should I do?
Should I set headers like that:

```
getMarkets() {
    const headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    headers.set('Accept', 'application/json');
    headers.set('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');
    headers.set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');

    const path = 'https://api.binance.com/api/v1/exchangeInfo';
    return this.http.get(path, {headers: headers});
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: There is not enough detail here to begin to guess. Consider using an asynchronous technique that correspond well to HTTP requests (i.e. **not** RxJS).

Comment: Why not RxJS? Could you explain?

Comment: RxJS is useful when you have a stream of zero or more results. With an HTTP request, you always have _one_ result. It is awkward and error prone and throws away the [language level facilities](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) that are available.

Answer (score 6):

You can't quite use it directly like that, Binance API does not set CORS headers, so Chrome and all major browsers will block the requests.
There is a bit more to it, but essentially, the api servers that need to enable support for CORS should set `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` to be `*` or a single domain `www.example.com`, this allows the browsers to prevent malicious code on a site to call and read the response of some data from other site you might be logged on to ( eg: bank info )
You can read more about it [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing)

One possible solution is to have your own server that proxies calls to binance

Another solution if you're testing things out is to use a CORS enabling extension like  [this one](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?hl=en)

Update: You can also use the websocket API if that satisfies your data needs [docs](https://github.com/binance-exchange/binance-official-api-docs/blob/master/web-socket-streams.md)

Update 2: Here's a good stackoverflow [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10636611/how-does-access-control-allow-origin-header-work?rq=1) on cors

Side note: If your bank's API server sets the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` to `*` then change banks :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this simple request without headers.

```
 this.http.get('https://api.binance.com/api/v1/exchangeInfo').subscribe(data => {
      this.results = data;
    });
  }
```

It work for me

Comment: It doesn't work for me. Could try console.log(this.results) ? Does it work?

Answer (score 0):

HttpHeaders is immutable. So you must write

```
const headers = new HttpHeaders().
    set('Content-Type', 'application/json').
    set('Accept', 'application/json').
    set('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type').
    set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
```

or

```
const headers = new HttpHeaders(
    {
      Content-Type:'application/json'),
      Accept:'application/json'),
      Access-Control-Allow-Headers:'Content-Type'),
      Access-Control-Allow-Origin:'*')
    })
```

Comment: Still in browser I have error: Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://api.binance.com/api/v1/exchangeInfo. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing).

Comment: @AdamAdamski you are getting a CORS error? Why didn't you include that information in your question?! Eliseo how is `set` acting immutably in your example? This doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Yes, I have cors error. I forgot mention about it in question. Could you help me with that?