# Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) issue in my Get Ajax request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, cors, cross-origin-read-blocking

I want to get data from a URL

> https://api.binance.com/api/v1/ticker/24hr

When I hit this url in POSTMAN using Get type, i get JSON data, but when I hit it with an AJAX call, I get this issue

> Failed to load https://api.binance.com/api/v1/ticker/24hr: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost' is therefore not allowed access.
>
> Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response https://api.binance.com/api/v1/ticker/24hr with MIME type application/json. See https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5629709824032768 for more details.

This is my code

```
$.get( "https://api.binance.com/api/v1/ticker/24hr", function( data ) {
  console.log(data);
});
```

If need be, I can also change my `$.get` to `$.ajax`. That won't be an issue.

Comment: Read some documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS

Comment: First thing $.get and $.ajax are same thing $.get in direct method to call $.ajax with type:"GET"

Comment: The service you're using is either deliberately or accidentally disallowing AJAX access by not supplying CORS headers in its responses. You can't change that. A bit of Googling finds that other people have had to implement a server-side proxy  to access this data. This answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48202982/binance-api-and-angular-4-httpclient is related.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50873764/cross-origin-read-blocking-corb take a look

Comment: See the *How to use a CORS proxy to get around “No Access-Control-Allow-Origin header” problems* section of the answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43871637/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource-whe/43881141#43881141